# How to get data from a form using JS/JQuery and pass info to a controller using yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

Im trying the following:

I have a form where some columns are created dynamically depending on the length of a certain array as follows:

```
<div class="row box-table">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel-heading bold panel-title">
            <!-- Referral Code -->
            <div class="col-xs-<?= $widthReferralCodeColumn ?> text-center">
                <span><?= Yii::t('app', 'Referral Code') ?></span>
            </div>
            <!-- Referral Code -->
            <!-- Pay Methods -->
            <?php foreach ($hbwellMarginsDataFillers[0]['payMethods'] as $key => $value): ?>
                <div class="col-xs-<?= $payMethodsColumnsWidth ?> <?= $style ?> text-center">
                    <span><?= $key ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            <!-- Pay Methods -->
            <!-- Actions -->
            <div class="col-xs-<?= $widthActionsColumn ?> text-center">
                <span><?= Yii::t('app', 'Actions') ?></span>
            </div>
            <!-- Actions -->
        </div>
        <!--<div data-key="%{id}" class="hidden row-model">-->
        <div data-key="%{id}" class="row-model">
            <div class="table row-type edit-model">
                <!--<form id="%{id}" method="post">-->
                <form id="formulario" method="post">
                    <?php foreach ($hbwellMarginsDataFillers as $hbwellMarginsDataFiller): ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- Referral Code -->
                            <div class="col-xs-<?= $widthReferralCodeColumn ?> <?= $style ?> text-center">
                                <span data-editable="false" class="toShow" style="display: block" data-id="HbwellMargins[referralCode]" data-original="%{referralCode}"><?= $hbwellMarginsDataFiller['referralCode'] ?></span>
                                <span data-editable="true" class="toHide" style="display: none">
                                    <div class="form-group hbwell-margins-referralCode"><input type="text" id="hbwell-margins-referralCode" name="HbwellMargins[referralCode]" value="<?= $hbwellMarginsDataFiller['referralCode'] ?>" class="form-control"></div>
                                </span>
                                <!-- ORIGINAL -->
                                <?/*= $hbwellMarginsDataFiller['referralCode'] */?>
                                <!-- ORIGINAL -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- Referral Code -->

                            <!-- Pay Methods -->
                            <?php foreach ($hbwellMarginsDataFiller['payMethods'] as $key => $value): ?>
                                <div class="col-xs-<?= $payMethodsColumnsWidth ?> <?= $style ?> text-center">
                                    <?php if($value === null): ?>
                                        <span data-editable="false" class="toShow" style="display: block" data-id="HbwellMargins[payMethods]" data-original="%{payMethods}">null</span>
                                        <span data-editable="true" class="toHide" style="display: none">
                                            <div class="form-group hbwell-margins-payMethods">
                                                <input type="text" id="hbwell-margins-payMethods" name="HbwellMargins[payMethods]" value="" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </span>
                                        <!-- ORIGINAL -->
                                        <!--<span>null</span>-->
                                        <!-- ORIGINAL -->
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <span data-editable="false" class="toShow" style="display: block" data-id="HbwellMargins[payMethods]" data-original="%{payMethods}"><?= $value ?></span>
                                        <span data-editable="true" class="toHide" style="display: none">
                                            <div class="form-group hbwell-margins-payMethods">
                                                <input type="text" id="hbwell-margins-payMethods" name="HbwellMargins[payMethods]" value="<?= $value ?>" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </span>
                                        <!-- ORIGINAL -->
                                        <!--<span><?/*= $value */?></span>-->
                                        <!-- ORIGINAL -->
                                    <?php endif ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                            <!-- Pay Methods -->

                            <!-- Actions -->
                            <!--<div class="col-xs-<?/*= $widthActionsColumn */?> text-center">
                                <a id="clickOnEdit" data-editable="false" class="toShow" style="display: block" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="%{id}" class="edit_button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil v-aling-middle icon edit"></span></a>
                                <button data-editable="true" class="toHide" style="display: none" data-request-id="10" role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-request accept"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
                                <a id="stopOnEdit" data-editable="true" class="toHide" style="display: none" data-request-id="10" role="button" class="hidden btn btn-sm btn-request cancel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                            </div>-->
                            <div class="col-xs-<?= $widthActionsColumn ?> text-center">
                                <a id="clickOnEdit" data-editable="false" class="toShow" style="display: block" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="%{id}" class="edit_button">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil v-aling-middle icon edit"></span>
                                </a>
                                <!--<button data-editable = "true" class="toHide" style="display: none" data-request-id="10" role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-request accept" type="submit" onclick="return epaCuliao();">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                                </button>-->
                                <a id="submitChanges" type="submit" onclick="return epaCuliao();" data-editable="true" class="toHide" style="display: none" data-request-id="10" role="button" class="hidden btn btn-sm btn-request accept">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                                </a>
                                <!--<button id="stopOnEdit" data-editable="true" class="toHide" style="display: none" data-request-id="10" role="button" class=" btn btn-sm btn-request cancel">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                </button>-->
                                <a id="stopOnEdit" data-editable="true" class="toHide" style="display: none" data-request-id="10" role="button" class="hidden btn btn-sm btn-request cancel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Actions -->
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When pencil icon is clicked form can be edited.

Well my problem is how to get all the information from that form and pass it to a function (actionEditHbwellMargins) in a controller (ClinicController).

I started using JS/JQuery copying code from other parts of my project, but I dont know how to get a solution in this case:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var editable_fields = {
    'referralCode': 'HbwellMargins[referralCode]',
    'payMethods': 'HbwellMargins[payMethods]',
};

document.getElementById('submitChanges').onclick = function() {
  edit();
}

function edit() {
    alert("Epa culiao");

    var el = $(this);
    var container = el.closest('.row-type.edit');
    var form = container.find("form");
    var id = form.attr('id');
    var values = {};
    var params = 'id='+encodeURI(id);

    $.each(editable_fields, function(key,key2){
        var input = container.find("[name=\""+key2+"\"]");
        var val = input.val();
        values[key2] = val;

        //para generar la url
           params += "&"+key+"="+encodeURI(val);
    });

    var thisapp = this;

    axios.post('/clinic/edit-hbwell-margins?'+params)
           .then(function (response) {
               $.each(values,function(key,val){
                   container.find("span[data-id=\""+key+"\"]")
                       .text(val)
                       .attr('data-original', val);

                   container.find("[name=\""+key+"\"]").val(val);
               });

               container.removeClass('editable');
           })
           .catch(function (error) {
               console.log(error);
               edit_cancel();
           });
   }

}
```

'payMethods': 'HbwellMargins[payMethods]' will be an array with variable length.

Please would you be so kind to help me or giving me some hint to achieve a solution? I'm desperate to find out a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: What is happening? Could you tell me what is wrong. Is there some error? Does the request get triggered? What does it return if so? I am not sure what is the issue here. What fails to work.

Comment: Sorry if I havent explained on my post...I have the problem to get all the info from form inputs and pass it to the function, my code in JS or JQuery doest work...im not an expert in these languages

Comment: But what exactly doesn't work? Nothing happens? An error is triggered? Is there some request sent to the controller(look in the network tab of the browser console)?

Comment: simply doesnt connect to my controller, and doesnt get the info that i store on my form input fields

Comment: It's not clear, you have a form and when you submit it, you want to pass the form fields to a controller action?